# ComboBox SelectValue returns the one before

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, selectedindex

I have a problem, basically I have a Windows Form application where I create a Theme and a Theme has an Id from an Atelier. This id is selected with a `ComboBox` that shows the Id of the Atelier from the Atelier table on my database.

Basically I choose an Atelier id with the combobox that is filled like that :

```cs
foreach (ListeAteliers listeAt in ListeAteliers.listeAteliers())
{
    cbCreaThemeAt.Items.Add(listeAt.idAt);
}
```

And then the Theme is created with the `SelectedIndex` of the `Combobox`:

```cs
try
{
    int iBd = cbCreaThemeAt.SelectedIndex;
    Themes TH;

    if (txbIdThemCrea.Text.Length != 0 && txbNomThemeCrea.Text.Length != 0 && cbCreaThemeAt.SelectedIndex != 0)
    {
        TH = new Themes(txbIdThemCrea.Text, txbNomThemeCrea.Text.ToString(), cbCreaThemeAt.SelectedIndex.ToString());
        monAssoc.LesThemes.Add(TH);
        TH.ajouterTheme(txbIdThemCrea.Text, txbNomThemeCrea.Text, cbCreaThemeAt.SelectedIndex.ToString());
    }
    else
    {
        lblConfirmCreaThemes.Text = "Erreur dans la création";
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Erreur dans la création : " + ex.ToString());
}
```

The problem that I have is that on the app, when I choose an Id with the combobox, when i create my object Theme, the id selected is going to be the one before.

Example : if i have three items : "1","2" and "3" and that I choose "3", the `SelectedIndex` is going to be "2"

My question is how can I make my `SelectedIndex` return the exact value I select on the `ComboBox` and why is it happening?

Comment: Indexes are zero based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SelectedIndex` returns the 0-based index of the selected item. The first item `"1"` has index 0 etc. You want to look at the [`SelectedItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.combobox.selecteditem?view=netcore-3.1) property that will return the actual selected item `"3"` and not its index which is indeed 2.

Comment: Thanks ! It helped me !